# Possible confusion with tag

Tags: support, tags

The tag [photosites](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photosites) has been used in the context of both image hosting websites and the individual "detectors" in the sensor. How should this be clarified?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I understood your question, and have offered an answer...I am guessing the term is not as well-known as sensel, pixel, photodiode, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A photosite is a photo sensitive area on a camera sensor. A photo site is a site to host photos. **Therefore I suggest [photosite] for the former and [photo-site] for the latter.**

Alternately we can replace the latter with [online] and [gallery] or [online-gallery] which makes the distinction clearer.

Comment: I think we can make photo-site a synonym for online-gallery or something similar. I think we should try to relegate photosite to the technical meaning for a photo-sensitive area on a camera sensor.

Comment: Anything that clearly distinguishes these tags would be useful