# Photo-galleries online and in real life - tagging

Tags: discussion, tagging

Related to [this question-answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/possible-confusion-with-tag) in meta.

The [photosite] tag seems sorted and has two questions tagged to it. Searching tags for *"online"* returns only  [online-shopping]. Searching tags for *"galler"* returns two tags:

[[photo-galleries](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-galleries)] and [[galleries](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galleries)]

Photo-galleries tag has 13 questions of which 2 are about real-life physical galleries. Galleries tag has only one question, which is about a real-life physical gallery. The rest of questions (11 of them) are about online-galleries. Would it be serving any good purpose to have all online-gallery questions under one tag and real-life gallery questions under another tag? And have Tag-wikis to distinguish the difference for future questions tagging.

EDIT: One more issue - Gallery or Galleries? Which one looks better as a tag? There is now three questions under [galleries] and new one under [gallery].

Comment: On the edit: we're really, really inconsistent about whether tags are plural or singular. I say go with whatever is currently more used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the concerns for online galleries are sufficiently different from physical galleries that a distinct tag is probably worth it.

Comment: Now who wants to do the legwork?

Comment: @dpollitt - I've done it now, as far as I can with this rep. Moved the two physical gallery questions under the tag with the already existing question, and then tried to summon a short and descriptive tagwiki-excerpts to direct future question traffic. Not sure if the wording is allright, but I guess somebody will edit if and when necessary :)